# How to connect local spark to Hive in cluster in Scala IDE

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Can you please let me know the steps to connect scala ide which I use for developing spark to connect to hive. Currently the output goes to hdfs and then I create an external table on top of it. But as spark streaming creates small files , the performance is getting bad and I want spark to write directly to Hive and I am not sure what configuration in my PC that I should make for that to happen for my development.

Comment: There's no such thing as writing directly to hive. Hive works on top of HDFS and that's where the data has to go anyway.  You may instead want to run another job to compact the many small files into bigger ones.

Comment: Thanks. How can you compact the small files to bigger ones. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what 's the format of the files ? Text ? Parquet ? Generally, you can use `coalesce` on the dataframe before writing it.  See https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4 . If you can't change how they are written, you can still read them then coalesce then write.

Comment: Thanks much. I will try. I am writing those files as ORC.